# Get access to iPhone camera live feed

Tags: objective-c

I need to get access to the actual camera on the iPhone and take a 'snapshot' of it every .X seconds.

On each update, I'll run image processing on it (a modified version of OpenCVCircles) and if conditions are met, exit out of the camera while taking certain actions. If conditions are not met, then I'll simply stay in the camera. The conditions will be a custom configuration of a series of circles that the user has to look at through the camera.

I know that this could be easy by forcing the user to take a picture, and I grab that from the UIImagePicker. However, I think it would be much better to do it automatically for the user, if they are in view of the image.

Is it possible to do this without completely writing my own Camera by AVCapture classes?

Comment: Removed my answer after seeing your edit. Why are AVCapture classes unsuitable for your use case ?

Comment: Didn't need to remove your answer - was still applicable! But I was trying to see if there was a way to do this without writing my own camera essentially. This will be my first time using them, so it just means that the project unfortunately will take longer if I dabble with AVCapture classes manually. But after looking at your response, I've started looking into the apple docs on the AVCapture classes

Comment: `AVCapture` is what you are going to need to use. And unless you can find something on github, or some other open source project, you will need to write it on your own. I wrote a camera class that was almost identical to the iOS camera app (minus panoramic, hdr, etc.) in less than a week, so it's not all that bad if you have to write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into AVCaptureSession, AVCaptureDevice and the like classes. They should provide what you need. We are using it here to provide a live video feed through the network.

**Edit**

From your question edit, I see this answer does not apply directly to your use case. Yet it is the only mean to my knowledge that will allow you to accomplish what you seek.